# The $route.query.page returns a wrong value or it's problem of type casting in the v-if condition

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

im making a posts page and the thing in focus is pagination.

I've created a pagination component that looks like this:

```
<template>
    <nav aria-label="Pagination">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
            <li class="page-item" v-if="currentPage !== 1">
                <a @click="previous" class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
            </li>
            <li v-for="page in getNumberOfPagesShow"
                v-bind:class="{ disabled: page === currentPage }"
                class="page-item">
                <a @click="clickPage(page)" class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    {{ page }}
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item" v-if="currentPage !== totalPages">
                <a @click="next" class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Next</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "pagination",
        props: ['app', 'onClickPage', 'totalPages', 'page'],
        data()
        {
            return {
                currentPage: this.page,
                lastPage: 0
            }
        },


        computed: {
            getNumberOfPagesShow()
            {
                if (this.totalPages > 10)
                {
                    return 10;
                }

                return this.totalPages;
            }
        },

        methods: {
            previous()
            {
                this.currentPage--;

                this.clickPage(this.currentPage);
            },

            next()
            {
                this.currentPage++;

                this.clickPage(this.currentPage);
            },

            clickPage(page)
            {
                this.currentPage = page;

                this.onClickPage(page);
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

and the component is called using

```
                <!-- Pagination Top -->

                <pagination :total-pages="thread.posts.last_page"
                            :page="app.$route.query.page"
                            style="margin-top: 20px;"
                            :on-click-page="clickPage">
                </pagination>
```

Everything works, except the `:page="app.$route.query.page"` attribute, which sets the `currentPage` inside the pagination component.

Now, this code doesn't work:

```
    <li class="page-item" v-if="currentPage !== 1">
        <a @click="previous" class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
    </li>
```

It's supposed to hide the previous button if current page is 1. However, this doesn't work, suggesting that `app.$route.query.page` is not getting the value correctly.

When I debug inside the `created()` method, I write

```
console.log(this.app.$route.query.page)
```

it does return the correct value. So I don't know what the problem is.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: try to add ` @click.prevent="previous"` and remove `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: the problem is not with the click button, its with getting the correct value for currentPage from this.app.$route.query.page

Comment: yes i know, but i suggest that as a good practice, but there's something that i can't understand is the `onClickPage` property

Comment: dont worry, everything regarding clicking works

Comment: i gonna ask to do this in your created hook `console.log(typeof(this.app.$route.query.page))` and give me the result in your console

Comment: great idea, it was string, so i parsed it into int and now it works! thanks a lot!

Comment: i will post that as answer if you want?

Comment: i just did thanks :)

Comment: you're welcome, i +1 ed your answer

Answer (score 1):

Great, the solution was to parse the prop `page` into int:

```
    data()
    {
        return {
            currentPage: parseInt(this.page),
            lastPage: 0
        }
    },
```